# Is there any way to delete all characters before the GET word?

Tags: sublimetext3, text-editor

I am using sublime text on windows and I have something like this.

```
race-position-18374327498.png:1 GET   https://google.com/example.png
race-position-453452.png:1 GET https://google.com/example1.png
race-position-343532.png:1 GET  https://google.com/example.png
race-position-4543646554764576574564.png: GET https://google.com/example22.png
race-position-5765865865843655.png: GET https://google.com/example434.png
```

I want to get rid of everything before the **GET** word so I want the output like this.

```
https://google.com/example.png
https://google.com/example1.png
https://google.com/example.png
https://google.com/example22.png
https://google.com/example434.png
```

Is there any way to do this in any software? Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: didn't this use to say Notepad++?

Comment: It has both tags, @Elsa please remove notepad++ if not relevant, as there are many slightly different implementions of regex so can cause confusion later :)

Comment: @DanielBrose Thanks for the explanation it helps a lot. Just removed the notepad++ tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually what you want is to delete everything before the `http` part of the uri. To do that use the find and replace box and use a regex for `^.*http` and replace it with `http` and it should remove them all

```
^ beginning of line  
.*  
  . any character
  * repeated
http string of `http`
```

this will match on any line that has a `http` in it(meaning it's also compatible with `https`) and all characters before it in a line and will replace them with `http`

[Documentation on the NotePad++ website about regular expressions](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#regular-expressions)

Answer (score 2):

For the data set you gave, which included lines without GET in them, simple **find+replace** regex

You can get to this using 'Find' then 'Replace' in top menu, or hitting "ctrl+h" anytime

1. **FIND** `.*\shttp`
2. **REPLACE** `http`

So it replaces any char until it finds a `(whitespace)http` match

The **whitespace** is a sanity check, since the left hand side might have "http" there, but highly unlikely to have whitespace following by http.

**EDIT**

@Robert Mennell comment made me realise i dont know if left hand side can contain whitespace, so here is improved regex for you to handle that

To be clear, both version work on the OP dataset, the improvement likely handles better if the simpler regex doesnt quite work on the full actual dataset now or in future :)

Feel free to use either though, i left the other one just above.

**FIND** `^(.*)\shttp([^\s]*)$`

**REPLACE** `http\2`

In **Regex**:

- `.` means any character
- `*` means 0-many
- `\s` is for whitespace
- `(` and `)` define groups
- `\1`, `\2` ect is how you call back to those groups
- `^` by itself is line start
- `[` and `]` is a character group
- `[^` means a negative character group (so any character but these)
- `$` is line end

The line start and ends just ensure each row treated seperate, and it handles whitespace on the left side by making sure the http has no whitespace AFTER it UNTIL end of line, using the `[^\s]*`, meaning any number of non-whitespace characters.

Using the `\2` in the replace puts all the text in that second `(` `)` group back in again.

So it handles http, https, and any characters after that too, and will only every retain content in the last right hand part of each line.

You can use even more flavourful versions to do same outcome, however in **sublime text 3** at least, find replace tool already has default modifiers so `.` wont replace newline characters and will find multiple matches, so its a very simple operation :)

Here is a great cheatsheet for regex as implemented by sublime text: https://jdhao.github.io/2019/02/28/sublime_text_regex_cheat_sheet/

Comment: they shouldn't need the whitespace as `.` should take care of it

Comment: @RobertMennell, i know thanks, i always like the sanity check though, just in case the filename (left part) has http somewhere in it, since it can never have a whitespace char in it.

Comment: filenames can have white space in them though?

Comment: @RobertMennell - thanks for that, since i dont know for sure the webserver or whatever tool would avoid\escape that, i improved my answer, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

In Sublime Text, you can also select the text " GET " and `ctrl+D` to select all " GET ", and then just press right arrow so yoir cursor will be at the end of GET word, then just `shift+home`. It will select all th content before GET. And then you can just delete it.

Though this won't be useful for longer file. But for for quickly do it for some lines you could use it. Its handy to do it.